# node.js server handle request callback function ending before writing response

Tags: node.js, http, callback

I have an http server with a handleRequest callback that runs another script in vm.runInNewContext for each request. The script that runs inside vm.runInNewContext makes some asynchronous http post requests and writes the server response only after getting the responses from the posts.
As a result, the code of handleRequest callback ends before the server response is written. 
Is it safe? or is there a way to avoid this situation?

Here is some code:

```
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(8080);

var handleRequest = function (request, response) {
    // get request data...

    var context = {
        ServerRequest : request,
        ServerResponse : response
     };

     var stringScript = // a string with the script that posts data
     var script = vm.createScript(stringScript);
     script.runInNewContext({ context: context });
}
```

the script string does this:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {....}
var req = request.get(options);

    req.on('response', function (res) {
            var chunks = [];
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                var encoding = res.headers['content-encoding'];
                if (encoding == 'gzip') {
                    zlib.gunzip(buffer, function(err, decoded) {
                        // set response headers and write the response
                        context.ServerResponse.end(decoded.toString()); 
                    });
                } else if (encoding == 'deflate') {
                    zlib.inflate(buffer, function(err, decoded) {
                    // set response headers and write the response                            
                    context.ServerResponse.end(decoded.toString());
                    })
                } else {
                    // set response headers and write the response                                                    
                    context.ServerResponse.end(buffer.toString());
                }
            });

    });
```

Comment: That's the whole idea of node. The methods should return, so that the server can continue processing other events in the event loop. And only after the callback is called does it return to processing this particular request.

Comment: The problem is that the vm.runInNewContext doesn't have a callback, and there is no way to make sure the response ends. In my real code, not all the scripts look like this, and they may not do response.end(), in that case, I would like to do it in the handleRequest, but it is already finished running in this context at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: Return a promise (e.g. use the [Q-library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)) from the VM-script.
`script.runInNewContext` will return whatever you return from the VM-script. That way you have a "callback" for when the VM code finishes.

```
// Script for VM
// I simplified it. Just resolve or reject the promise whenever you are done with your work
'use strict';

var defer = q.defer();

doABarrelRoll(function() {
  defer.resolve('RESULT');
});

defer.promise; // This line will return the promise.
```

When returning a value from a VM-script, you do not need any return construction. Just write the thing you want and let the magic happen.

```
// Script for current context
'use strict';

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(8080);

var handleRequest = function (request, response) {
  // get request data...

  var context = {
    ServerRequest : request,
    ServerResponse : response
  };

  var stringScript = // a string with the script that posts data
  var script = vm.createScript(stringScript);
  var prom = script.runInNewContext({
    context: context,
    q: require('q'),
  });

  prom.done(function ($result) {
    console.log('VM finished with result: ' + $result);
  });
}
```